# Imprimir JSON ordenado en HTML, usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

Estoy realizando llamadas al RestAPI de Facebook y obteniendo información de él. El problema es que la informacion se imprime de una manera muy dificil de leer y me preguntaba si hay alguna manera de que el JSON aparezca con un formato mas claro. Esta es mi llamada al API:

```
        FB.api(
                  '/ads_archive',
                  'GET',
                  {"ad_reached_countries":"ES","acces_token":"{}","fields":"ad_creation_time,ad_creative_body,funding_entity","bylines":"[\"Podemos\"]","search_terms":"Podemos","search_page_ids":"","ad_active_status":"all","limit":"50","ad_type":"POLITICAL_AND_ISSUE_ADS"},
                  function(response) {
                      console.log(response);
                      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                  }
                );
        
    }
```

Y este el output que obtengo al imprimir la informacion con innerHTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria conseguir que se imprimiese de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!!

Comment: Saludos. Con `lodash` ( https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15 ) puedes hacer muchas cosas con elementos tipo arreglo; en tu caso sería usar `sortBy`.

Comment: Podrias darle formato asi: `JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2);` tendra un identacion de 2 espacios

Comment: Apps de navegadores como JSON formattter harán una salida asi como la esperas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por supuesto que puedes hacerlo. Para ello te puedes apoyar en la etiqueta [`<pre></pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre), que establece:

> El texto en este elemento típicamente se muestra en una fuente fija, no proporcional, exactamente como es mostrado en el archivo. Los espacios dentro de este elemento también son mostrados como están escritos.

Además debes usar el método [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) del Objeto Global JSON, el cual acepta 3 argumentos:

- `value`: El valor JSON a ser convertido en cadena.
- `replacer`: una función que altera el comportamiento de la conversión (en tu caso no haría falta y la estableces a `undefined`).
- `spacer`: Un tipo `String` o un tipo `Number` que especifica el tabulado o espaciado para identar la cadena de texto.

Por ejemplo:

```js
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(json => {
  document.getElementById('salida').textContent = JSON.stringify(json.results[0], undefined, 2);
})
.catch(error => {
  document.getElementById('salida').textContent = JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2);
})
```

```html
<pre id="salida"></pre>
```

**Nota**

Como comentario final, evita usar el atributo o propiedad [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) cuando insertes texto desde otra fuente dinámicamente en tu web, esto por [razones de seguridad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Consideraci%C3%B3n_de_seguridad). Es preferible usar el atributo o propiedad [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).