# ¿Cómo hacer fetch a una URL que es un JSON y mostrar el contenido en HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

Esto es lo que tengo en el JScript lo que hace que el contenido del JSON aparezca en la consola, pero no sé cómo hacer para que ese contenido aparezca en mi HTML utilizando por ejemplo createTextNode o innerHTML. Recién empiezo en esto.

```
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
         console.log(myJson);
       });
```

Comment: ¿En qué elemento deseas mostrarlo? ¿Un `<div>` o un `<p>`, o cuál?

Comment: Cualquier forma me serviría pero digamos que un DIV

Comment: Pues asigna un `id` a tu elemento, y luego cuando obtienes el `json` le asignas el mismo al valor de la propiedad `innerText`, aunque no se verá con un formato muy bonito, al menos podrás ver el resultado en tu HTML. Por ejemplo: `document.getElementById(<id_de_tu_div>).innerText = json;`. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir JSON ordenado en HTML, usando JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369935/imprimir-json-ordenado-en-javascript)

Comment: Probé eso y no funcionó, probé a guardar todo el fetch en una variable y hacer eso que dijiste pero en lugar de innerText = json puse innerText=variable y tampoco funcionó. probé también a igualar eso mismo a MyJson como dice en el código de arriba y en el navegador me aparece [object Promise].

Comment: El `fetch` es una Promesa, por lo tanto no sirve de nada guardarlo en una variable. Tu pregunta es duplicada de la que pongo en el motivo de cierre.

Comment: Si recién estás empezando, sería prudente fijar ciertos [conceptos fundamentales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn) antes de hacer uso de API's como `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de que formato deseas mostrar la informacion. Analizando el contenido del recurso, podrias mostrar el contenido tal cual (formateado)

```
var element=document.createElement("pre");
     element.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(myJson,null," ");
     document.body.appendChild(element);
```

U organizarlo para mostrarlo de manera mas estructurada:

```
for(field in myJson.message){
       var element=document.createElement("b");
       element.innerHTML=field;
       document.body.appendChild(element);
       var items=document.createElement("ul");
       items.innerHTML=myJson.message[field].join(",");
       document.body.appendChild(items);
     }
```

```js
fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
     // mostrar los datos JSON (formateado con tabulaciones)
     var element=document.createElement("pre");
     element.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(myJson,null," ");
     document.body.appendChild(element);
     
     //crear un formato basado en los datos
     for(field in myJson.message){
       var element=document.createElement("b");
       element.innerHTML=field;
       document.body.appendChild(element);
       var items=document.createElement("p");
       items.innerHTML=myJson.message[field].join(",");
       document.body.appendChild(items);
     }
   });
```

Comment: La pregunta fue marcada como duplicada por una razón. Relacionado: [¿Estamos utilizando demasiado poco el cierre por duplicado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4757/estamos-utilizando-demasiado-poco-el-cierre-por-duplicado-no-usamos-demasiado). Saludos